# ControlTemplate Content Not Resizing

Tags: maui, maui-windows

I am trying to achieve a templated view on my pages which displays a standard header and footer where my content goes in the middle. To achieve this I decided to use a ControlTemplate and reference this on each page.

In my resource dictionary I have the following:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MoneyTemplate">

        <Grid
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BackgroundColor}"
            Padding="25">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Source="buddy.png" />

<tabView:SfTabView
Grid.Row="1"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                TabBarPlacement="Bottom">
                <tabView:SfTabItem Header="Overview" TextColor="Black">
            <ContentPresenter  />
                </tabView:SfTabItem>
                <tabView:SfTabItem Header="Scheduler">
                    <Label Text="Hello world" />
                </tabView:SfTabItem>
            </tabView:SfTabView>

            
            <Label
                Grid.Row="2"
                Text="Hello" />
        </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>
```

And on my pages I implement with:

```
<ContentView 
        VerticalOptions="Fill"
        ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MoneyTemplate}">PAGE CONTENT GOES HERE</ContentView>
```

When I implement this in a Windows application and resize my window the control does not update, however if I stop using a ControlTemplate and paste this xaml directly into the page everything renders correctly.

I realise that MAUI is still in preview but I'm unsure of whether the problem is the way I've written the template and whether my understanding is off or whether this is a bug within MAUI.

Comment: That does sound like a Maui ControlTemplate bug. Does it happen if you use only `<Label>`s (replace `Image` and `tabView:SfTabView` with Labels)?